# Can't connect to server via SSH

Tags: ssh, router

I'm trying to connect to an AWS server with SSH. But for some reason I can't. When I run below:
`ssh -i <keypair.pem> ec2-user@<ip> -vvv`

I get:
`OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<ip>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <ip> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file <keypair.pem> type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file <keypair.pem>-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4`

I'm guessing this is a router ip ban configuration problem? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions and contents of your remote .ssh directory. Do have your public key in the authorized_keys file?  See the following links

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/unix/ssh-auth-keys-jsp-135687.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server